# How can we say that a wave function follows Schrödinger equation using operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

If I have an operator which has an eigenfunction which satisfies Schrödinger's time-dependent equation, and I have another eigenfunction of this operator, can I say that the other eigenfunction will also follow the Schrödinger's time dependent equation ?
$$Âf_1=k_1f_1$$ $$Âf_2=k_2f_2$$ 
Let Â be the operator, $f_1$ and $f_2$ the eigenfunctions, $k_1$ and $k_2$ the respective eigenvalues, and $f_1$ satisfies Schrödinger's time-dependent equation. So, can I say that $f_2$ does that as well ?

Comment: Comment to question (v3): The question essentially boils down to the following: _If $\psi(x,t)$ is an eigenvector for an operator $\hat{A}$ for all times $t$, will $\psi(x,t)$ satisfies the TDSE?_ Answer: _No, not necessarily. Take e.g. $\hat{A}\equiv\hat{0}$ as the zero operator._

Answer (score 1):

No. The simplest counter example will be an operator which just multiplies any argument by some value, i.e. $Âf=k_f\cdot f$ for all $f$. Here every function is an eigenfunction. This $k_f$ might be an overall constant, or the number of zeros of $f$, or whatever.

Wether one possible argument function $f$ is subject to any kind of condition (such as $i\hbar\dot f-Hf\overset{!}{=}0$) doesn't interestest this operator.

Comment: suppose Â IS an energy operator will my statement hold true ?

Comment: If by energy operator you mean that it's a function value of $H$, i.e. $Â=F(H)$, for example $Â:=4H+H^4$, then $Â$ and $H$ have the same eigenfunctions. (I'm pretty sure about this, certainly in the common cases, but not in general. Look up the spectral theorem. Maybe there are pathological functional analysis scenarios I can't think of right now, it happens sometimes. You know, such that if $F$ is ill-behaved, the domain of $H$ and $F(H)$ is different etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question makes much sense, because it is based on a possible confusion.

One has to keep in mind that the time-dependent Schroedinger equation is using an object, $i\partial_t$, which is not an operator on the Hilbert space. Furthermore, the SE is applied from "outside" (it is an additional postulate), and it does not make sense to ask if one state follows it or not.